# Excel warning message on table autoexpand

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel xlsm worksheet with a defined table that has a header and 1 empty row which would autoexpand when data is added. Please see screenshot for a dummy example.

When adding rows manually, it will autoexpand and work fine. I will start to have problems when pasting data into the table which is the objective.

In case pasting anything from 2 rows or more into cell B2, I will get the warning message as presented on screenshot. The only way no warning is shown is if I add data one by one manually OR paste data into cell B3, i.e. leave the first row empty, which I'm reluctant to do.

Just to clarify - things work fine for a new dummy table, but I'd really need to fix my existing table which otherwise works great for XML-export.

Also - expansion of the "live" table range works as expected. The suspicious part is that I'm presented this warning message which is not a standard procedure. However the tangible problem at hand is the set formulas in column A that are outside the table range, set and are not supposed to autoexpand (but are referring to cells within the table).

The formula in the cell `A2` would stay the same, however formula in `A3` would turn from `=B3&C3` into something like `=B6&C6`

While it might be difficult to pinpoint the exact issue - maybe someone has ideas what could cause this warning message to be shown on table autoexpansion in the first place ?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to turnoff Auto expendable Off ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually caused by the fact that, in column `A` you have references to the cells below the Table that you then paste data into. The warning dialog is simply alerting you to the fact that the formula in column `A` have been changed.

The solution is to replace the normal references in the formulas in column `A` with structured references.

The appropriate formula for all the cells in column `A` would thus be:

```dart
=IFERROR(YourTableName[Quantity]&YourTableName[Item],"")
```

---

**Notes:**

Don't forget to replace `YourTableName` with your *actual* table name.

The simple way to get the structured references for cells in a Table is to click on the Table cells when typing in the formula.